# Unit test with promise not working

Tags: node.js, unit-testing, promise, mocha.js, bluebird

Im using mocha to test my api, the problem is that this function is async and 
the test suite called before I getting the resutls from the function, how can I overcome this?

I try to chain the test like following which raise an error Empty test suite.

```
describe("Validations", function () {

    var validator = require('../utils/validator');
    var isValid = null;

    validator.validateJS()
        .then(function (args) {
            isValid = args;
        }).then(function(){
        it("init validations ", function () {
            expect(isValid).to.equal('valid1');
        });
    });

})
```

My initial usage is like following which if is call to the it and expect inside before the 
answer(isValid) is coming from the promise,any idea?

```
describe("Validations", function () {

    var validator = require('../utils/validator');
    var isValid = null;



    validator.validateJS()
        .then(function (args) {
            isValid = args;

        }).done();

    it("init validations ", function () {
        expect(isValid).to.equal('valid1');
    });

})
```

Comment: Is the validatJS a miss-spell here or it's in your code also?

Comment: @VassilisPits - typo , thanks:) any idea how to run this test?

Comment: Why not use mocha's `before()`?

Comment: @Fissio - can you please provide example?

Comment: @RaynD check the answer below

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use mocha's `before()`.

```
describe("Validations", function () {

    var validator = require('../utils/validator');
    var isValid = null;

    before(function(done) {
        validator.validateJS()
        .then(function (args) {
            isValid = args;
            done();
        })
    })

    it("init validations ", function () {
        expect(isValid).to.equal('valid1');
    });
})
```